# Command line to find units in a p2 repository using p2 query language

Tags: eclipse, p2, update-site

p2 has a [query language](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Query_Language_for_p2) that allows to run queries on the content of a p2 repository. However all examples in the [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Query_Language_for_p2) assume that the query language is used from within Java, e.g.

```
IQuery<IInstallableUnit> q = QueryUtil.createMatchQuery("this.id == $0", id);
metadataRepository.query(q);
```

How can I execute a query from the command line (without writing my own Java application)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) has an option to list or query the content of the given p2 repositories. With `-list` you'd get all units, and with `-list Q:<p2 QL collection query>` you can query for a subset.

The expression needs to be a collection query, so instead of the match query in the example given above, you need to use the equivalent collection query. Also, placeholders like `$1` must be replaced by the actual values.

Example: The command line to look for the all `org.eclipse.sdk.ide` units in the Juno release train repository would be

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
   -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno \
   -list 'Q:everything.select(x | x.id == "org.eclipse.sdk.ide")'
```

As a more useful example, you could use this command to find all units which are shown in categories in the p2 user interface (although I wouldn't try a large repository, the query seems to be quite slow):

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
   -repository <URL of some small repository> \
   -list 'Q:everything.select(y | everything.select(x | x.properties ~= filter("(org.eclipse.equinox.p2.type.category=true)")).collect(x | x.requirements).flatten().exists(r | y ~= r))'
```

Answer (score 0):

[p2diff](https://github.com/irbull/p2diff) tool written by Ian Bull is is well worth mentioning. His [article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-p2-tutorial-managing-metadata/) provides an overview of the p2 API and introduces some of the key concepts that should be understood to work with the p2 API.