# Eclipse p2 director application cannot update a feature

Tags: eclipse, p2, command-line-interface, nodeclipse, p2-director

I am developing [Node.js script to install Eclipse plugins](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates) by using [Eclipse built-in p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html). And p2-director fails to update features in some cases.

```
D:\Workspaces\Nodeclipse-DEV\nodeclipse-1\org.nodeclipse.ui\templates>node nodeclipse-install.js install -repository jar:file:/D:/Workspaces/Nodeclipse-DEV/nodeclipse-1/org.nodeclipse.site/target/org.nodeclipse.site-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.zip!/ maven
Nodeclipse CLI Installer (Eclipse Plugin Manager epm)
starting eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:/D:/Workspaces/Nodeclipse-DEV/nodeclipse-1/org.nodeclipse.site/target/org.nodeclipse.site-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.zip!/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -tag org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false
Installing org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201402180840.

Installation failed.

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402180840 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201402180840)
 Software currently installed: Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402170319 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201402170319)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once:
  Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402180840 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.jar 0.10.0.201402180840)
  Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402170319 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.jar 0.10.0.201402170319)
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402170319 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201402170319)
  To: org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.jar [0.10.0.201402170319]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Enide Maven 0.10.0.201402180840 (org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201402180840)
  To: org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.jar [0.10.0.201402180840]
Application failed, log file location: E:\Eclipse\Enide-Studio-2014-try2-win64\eclipse\configuration\1392717353881.log

eclipsec process exit code 13
```

I also tried passing both `.feature.jar` and `feature.group`.

```
eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:/D:/Workspaces/Nodeclipse-DEV/nodeclipse-1/org.nodeclipse.site/target/org.nodeclipse.site-0.10.0-SNAPSHOT.zip!/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -tag org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false
```

This maybe related to the fact that `.maven` feature includes `.maven` and `.common` plugins. `.common` plugin is also used by other features.
However this also happens with other features, that have no shared dependencies. p2 director help page does not specify the logic nor gives references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the p2 director level, there is no 'update' operation. Instead, you need to tell the director to both 'uninstall' and 'install' the IU that you want to be updated:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -installIU org.nodeclipse.enide.maven.feature.feature.group -repository ...
```

Comment: I wonder if plugin settings are preserved and if it will be atomic operation, i.e. if install fails, then uninstall should not be applied...

Comment: p2 has commit/rollback logic, so operations should be atomic.

Comment: You can update p2 feature (in any profile) using `IProvisioningAgent` and `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.UpdateOperation`  but  it's not exposed as a command-line tool.