# Eclipse p2 director application logs?

Tags: eclipse, p2, p2-director

I have created my own product using tycho. Everything works fine. Now I was trying to use the p2 director application on that product to list and install/uninstall features from a local repo. However, no mather what i do I do not get any result.

The command use (with and without the -console argument) is:

```
myapp.exe -console 
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/3.7/R-20181212-1410
-list
```

The application starts and is posible to use it.

I have checked that the bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app is present and is activated.

However I can not see and logs or report from the p2 director app and also I do not see any error indication.

There are also not logs in the workspace/.metadata directory or in the configuration directory

What should I be expecting?

I also try the -uninstallIU option to try uninstall one of the optional features included with the product but the results are the same. No messages, no nothing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208348/6505250

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quite interesting. However, I believe my issue is more related to the fact that I am running a RAP application and not an RCP application

Comment: RAP contains the same p2 director as all other RCP applications: `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director` == `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director`.

Comment: I created a testApp besides the default app. I configured the plugin.xml accordingly and materialize the product. Then I tried to run the testApp using: myApp.exe -application testAppId. However the testApp was not executed. Thus, i believe the issue is not on the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app. It could be that i am missing something and that is why the testApp is not running. In RAP the application are only created after the user connect to one of the applications entry points.